# A RenderFlex overflowed by 1.00 pixels on the bottom. The relevant error-causing widget was Column

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen which contains a togglebutton widget followed by a card widget which contains a form, followed by another card widget. I searched about this error and the suggested fix is to add an expanded widget. However, I am a noob and I don't know where to add the Expanded widget. Will appreciate your help.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your Cart'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: 
        Column
      (
      // child: Expanded(

       // child:Column(
         
        children: <Widget>[
            
            SizedBox(height: 10),
           if(cart.totalAmount > 0)ToggleButtons(
                borderColor: Colors.black26,
                fillColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                borderWidth: 2,
                selectedBorderColor: Colors.black,
                selectedColor: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                        'I will pickup',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                        'Please deliver',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    ),
                ],
                onPressed: (int index) {
                 //   print('index ' + index.toString()); 
                    setState(() {
                     // print('Inside state changed'); 
                    for (int i = 0; i < _isSelected.length; i++) {
                        print(_isSelected[i] = i == index); 
                        _isSelected[i] = i == index; 
                    }
                    });
                },
                isSelected: _isSelected,
                ),

          SizedBox(height: 10),
          if(_isSelected[1]) AddressScreen(),
           SizedBox(height: 10),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: cart.items.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => CartItem(
                    cart.items.values.toList()[i].id,
                    cart.items.keys.toList()[i],//returns productId 
                    cart.items.values.toList()[i].price,
                    cart.items.values.toList()[i].quantity,
                    cart.items.values.toList()[i].title,
                  ),
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Total',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Chip(
                    label: Text(
                      '\Tsh. ${cart.totalAmount.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.title.color,
                      ),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
           OrderButton(cart: cart)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ), 
        ],
      ),
      )
     //   ),
    //  ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
A RenderFlex overflowed by 1.00 pixels on the bottom.
```

The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
lib\screens\cart_screen.dart:40
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

> Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to
> force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space
> instead of being sized to their natural size. This is considered an
> error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot
> be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available
> space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it
> in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like
> a ListView.
>
> The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#d61dc
> relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your column in SingleChildScrollView( child: Column(.....))
you can remove the container as well in body if not using any of its properties and directly say body: SingleChildScrollView(...)